# Downloading and Uploading FFmpeg

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg

I have a Windows OS for development, and a Linux server. I downloaded ffmpeg on my Windows, configured everything, and uploaded the application. The video conversion didn't work. After extensive hours figuring out the culprit, I realized that I downloaded the ffmpeg for Windows, and need to download the Linux version. That seemed harder than downloading the Windows version. I have scoured the net, and have come up with squat

So, my 2 questions are:

1. Is there an easy way to download/install the linux version of ffmpeg? OR
2. Is there an easier way to install it straight on the server?

If it matters, I also have a Linux OS development, but found it hard to install ffmpeg on it anyway.

**Update:** After trying `apt-get install ffmpeg` on my Ubuntu Linux OS, it says it has already been installed. How do I locate what folder it's located?

Comment: Try `apt-get install ffmpeg`. If that doesn't work you'll have to give some details about which distribution you're using.

Comment: What distribution of Linux are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Linux.

Most applications aren't "installed to a folder". Most executables are installed into the directory `/usr/bin/`, most libraries into the directory `/usr/lib/`, and so on. The [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) contains a good description of how directories are used on Linux systems, though I'll caution you that it is *not* a standard -- it is descriptive not proscriptive.

To run `ffmpeg`, just type `ffmpeg --help` at the prompt.

If you really want to see the full path to `ffmpeg`, run `type ffmpeg` at the shell prompt:

```
$ type ffmpeg
ffmpeg is /usr/bin/ffmpeg
$
```

Comment: Thanks, buddy. It works nice. Now, loading it online, and seeing what happens.